# Memory align of instances of classes

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-alignment

I have read recently [interesting article](http://cultureofdevelopment.com/blog/how-we-sped-up-random-forest-processing-lots-of-common-performance-patterns/?utm_source=csharpdigest&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=featured) about performance.

There, author defined `struct` as follows:

```
public struct DecisionTreeNode
{
  public short ShortValue;
  public float FloatValue;
  public byte ByteVal1;
  public byte ByteVal2;
}
```

Inseance of this `struct` is 8 bytes.

All clear, but then he suggested that in order to gain performance, author writes:

> This [memory] alignment issue means it can be a fair bit more expensive to load the non aligned value. Luckily, the fix is really simple, you just swap the order of the fields in your class definition.

So he does that:

```
public struct DecisionTreeNode
{
  public float FloatValue;
  public short ShortValue;
  public byte ByteVal1;
  public byte ByteVal2;
}
```

How order fo fields in a class can affect way of storing instance in memory? How it affects mentioned alignment?

Comment: I guess, the alignment is 4 bytes. In the first case `short` and `float` don't fit 4 bytes, but in the second case last three elements fit 4 bytes perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a very good explanation here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.7

https://kalapos.net/Blog/ShowPost/DotNetConceptOfTheWeek13_DotNetMemoryLayout

Everything is all about the Pack field (is the size of its largest element or the specified packing size attribute => [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=X)] whichever is smaller).

According to the Pack field the struct will group fields sequentially into a Pack size  and add empty bytes to fit the Pack field.

struct => 1byte + 8byte + 1byte => Pack field => 8 => 8 + 8 + 8 = 24bytes

struct => 1byte + 1byte + 8byte => Pack field => 8 => 8 (1+1+6 empty bytes) + 8 = 16 bytes.

As you can see always group fields using the Pack field size.